# to send email with different 'from' email address using gmail smtp server in django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

I want to send an email to users with different **from** field values using **smtp gmail server** from the **django app**. I am able to send the mail successfully to users but the from field does not take the value that I provide in send_mail() but instead takes the EMAIL_HOST_USER value defined in settings.py

From field value should take any domain email address i.e.

```
  a mail from: xyz@yahoo.co.in or .com 
     or  from: abc@hotmail.com 
     or  so on
```

How can I achieve this behavior? Please help. I am new to using django and email functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot forge an email using Google's SMTP server. They will keep on using the current user's information (the login credentials you supplied). If you want to "change"/forge the email header, use your own email server/SMTP

Comment: if I don't want to use any smtp server, can I achieve the functionality that I want in django by some other way?

Comment: I am not fully sure but most of the time, pyhton usually runs over a linux environment which have a built-in mail sending feature. (depends on how the OS was installed)