# changing from address on send_mail

Tags: django

I've hooked in Gsuite as my SMTP server. It sends out emails and it works very well. However, when using the send_mail function in django, I want to indicate a from address other than the email address that I have hooked into Gsuite, which is admin@mywebsite.com.

```
    subject = 'Order Confirmation'
    from_email = "jim@gmail.com"
    to_email = ("james@gmail.com",)
    txt_message = "some text"
    html_message = "some other text"

    send_mail(subject,
             txt_message,
             from_email,
             to_email,            
             html_message=html_message,
             fail_silently=False,
             auth_user="admin@mywebsite.com", 
             auth_password="PASSWORD"
             )
```

When an email is sent out with this code, when I look at the resulting email email in the email client of james@gmail.com, the "from" address is admin@mywebsite.com rather than jim@gmail.com.

Is there a way that I can change this so that the 'from' is jim@gmail.com or at least the 'reply-to' is jim@gmail.com?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting in projects settings.py?

Comment: I don't want to use default_from_email. that's why i'm specifying a custom from addresss on each email sent.

Comment: The `from_email` argument in `send_email` should override the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this answers it. Gmail won't allow me to forge a from address, therefore the from address will always be admin@mywebsite.com

[to send email with different 'from' email address using gmail smtp server in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728288/to-send-email-with-different-from-email-address-using-gmail-smtp-server-in-dja)

Answer (score 2):

Gmail doesn't allow you to change the From address when sending email through its servers.

Sources:

[change sender address when sending mail through gmail in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871577/change-sender-address-when-sending-mail-through-gmail-in-c-sharp)

[How to change from-address when using gmail smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server)

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en