# Cannot set a sender email address in Django or Wagtail send_mail

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail, smtplib, wagtail-admin

The task: There is a website, offering a newsletter. I´m sending a newsletter subscription notification to an email address everytime a subscriber subscribes. For this I use send_mail from wagtail.admin.mail – I think it´s not relevant in which way I´m using send_mail.

The problem: I provide a from_email, but for some reason the email I receive contains the EMAIL_HOST_USER as sender – which is the email of the google mail account used for sending emails. I also tried `from django.core.mail import send_mail` but it´s the same. Is there any clue, how I can manage to make it work? Maybe they block to use custom email address showed as a sender?

Details: smtp.gmail.com and django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend is used for the email backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `django.core.mail.message.EmailMessage`

You can explicitly set all the message properties in that class, including the connection and the `from_email`

For connection, because I use different credentials across my site, I have a model to store connection settings and pull the relevant one for the job in hand.

For instance, in my `Contact` form class, I have a property for the mail settings:

```
@property
def mail_settings(self):
    email_settings=EmailSettings.objects.filter(type='contact').first()
    if email_settings:
        use_ssl = getattr(email_settings, 'use_ssl')
        return {
            'host' : getattr(email_settings, 'host'),
            'port' : getattr(email_settings, 'port'),
            'username' : getattr(email_settings, 'username'),
            'password' : getattr(email_settings, 'password'),
            'ssl_setting' : use_ssl,          
            'tls_setting' : not use_ssl
        }
```

then in the `send_mail()` method, I get the connection with `django.core.mail.get_connection`

```
    connection = mail.get_connection(**self.mail_settings)
```

You can pass this connection into the `EmailMessage` constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I didn´t know this and use django.core.mail.message.EmailMessage now. But unfortunately smtp.gmail.com doesn´t allow from_email.

Comment: Ok, but since you can define the email account for any message at runtime, do you need 'send as' or just swap in the actual sending account?

Comment: I use smtp.gmail.com and set the from_email in the message - the restriction applies to using a 'from' address not associated with the account that you form the smtp connection with.

Comment: Okay. With this action it can be achieved what I want to do. Thanks again.

Comment: [These are instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) to add valid from_email addresses within the google account.

Answer (score 0):

I checked again. The Gmail SMTP server indeed doesn´t allow to use a custom from_email. But the sender can be set in the account settings. As discussed above.

Source:
[changing from address on send_mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472331/changing-from-address-on-send-mail)